# Questions pertaining to "Disciples of the Night" achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Do you have to have two level 60 demon hunters on your account at the SAME time, or do you just have to achieve level 60 with two different ones.

For example, can you make one to level 60, delete them and then re-create another up until level 60 to get the achievement?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't need both at the same time, not entirely certain though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes you can

The achievement only requires you to level up two Demon Hunters, there is no requirement that both Demon Hunters still exist.